# Why didn't Batman just knock down the Joker while he had the chance?

Tags: batman-arkham-asylum

In the early stages of *Batman Arkham Asylum*, after Batman defeats the giant mutant prisoner, the Joker gives him a chance to take him down for good:

Although it was probably the Joker's intent, it seems Batman saw something in that particular scene that made him withdraw.

Knowing the Batman, I'm pretty sure he could have come up with a plan that would have trapped the Joker somehow and stopped his carnage in the asylum - ending all of the game story right there.

But why did Batman stop before taking down the Joker?

Comment: That it would stop the game right there is probably the reason it doesn't happen.

Comment: @TZHX It still doesn't explain why he didn't take any action and just 'stood' there...

Comment: I always read this scene about Joker offering Batman a chance to **kill** him, which is against Batman's rules.

Comment: @originaluser He could still try to stop him instead of killing him, it's the Batman we're talking about.
He would find a way to do so.

Comment: @HashiramaSenju True, however if you look at the situation Joker is in a pretty dangerous position (perched on an elevator), so I really don't think there was a safe way to capture him.

Comment: @originaluser Batman already done the impossible many times, he would manage (somehow).

Comment: Because the game developers knew it would make for a terrible story?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason Batman didn't knock off Joker in that part of the game was because it would kill the Joker. Bruce Wayne's (Batman's) parents were killed in front of him when he was young, so when Bruce vowed to fight crime in Gotham he swore not to kill because that would make him no better than the criminals he defeats.

This is seen played out in that exact scene. Joker stands precariously on the edge of the container, inviting Batman to knock him off and kill him, enticing him to "*end this once and for all*". Batman almost gives in to Joker's prodding, but stops himself just in time. Joker, knowing Batman's rule, then tells him he is "*getting too predictable*" as he escapes.